# Bash command to append to /boot/config.txt

Tags: raspbian, bash

I am trying to append text to the /boot/config.txt file but for some reason this is not working with the latest Raspbian(2016-05-27)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo echo 'dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt' >> /boot/config.txt
-bash: /boot/config.txt: Permission denied
```

Any clues why this is not working or is there another way to append text to a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The redirection takes place before sudo takes effect.

Try something like

`sudo sh -c "echo 'dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt' >> /boot/config.txt"`